# Could not find a match for std::multimap error

Tags: c++, cc

I am trying to compile a C++ application on SUN server using the compiler Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc Patch 124863-01.
I am getting an error saying

```
Error: Could not find a match for std::multimap<std::string, OutputNamespace::FUPInfo, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, OutputNamespace::FUPInfo>>>::insert(std::pair<std::string, OutputNamespace::FUPInfo>) needed in operator<<(std::ostream &, Output&)
```

The same application was compiled with a previous version of CC compiler, so this is a compiler specific issue? this is related to some flag to be set during the compilation?
Any idea please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `#include<map>`? `#include<utility>`? `#include<string>`? `#include<iostream>`? Please show us some code...

Comment: There appears to be much missing from this compiler in terms of C++ Standard conformity:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/documentation/cplusplus-faq-355066.html

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not conform to the C++ standard.

[This blog](http://sahajtechstyle.blogspot.com/2007/11/whats-wrong-with-sun-studio-c.html) talks about the problem in depth, with suggested work-arounds.

They suggest compiling with  `-library=stlport4`  if you don't want to modify/wrap multimap.